# Stop the auto migration of the schema in the sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

In [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org), how can we stop the automigration of the schema into the database. Sometimes,it gives error due to the migration. Is there a way that we can make the migration run only when the application is deployed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also try something like this:

```
module.exports = {

  // migrate: 'alter', // adds and/or removes columns on changes to the schema 

  // migrate: 'drop', // drops all your tables and then re-creates them. All data is deleted.

  // migrate: 'safe', doesn't do anything on sails lift- for use in production.

  attributes: { /* ... */ }

};
```

Comment: @mikermcneil, I tried to use this but after few days my data has vanished somehow,, I do not know how, I use this command forever -w  start -al /var/log/mylog.log --prod

Comment: Any thoughts @mikermcneil,,

Comment: @user3656084 if you use `migrate:safe`, you'll be good to go  (also note that if you run your app with `NODE_ENV=production`, this will happen automatically)

Comment: @mikermcneil Do you know the answer for this question please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007526/step-by-step-guide-to-using-a-migrating-tool-for-production-sailsjs-system

Answer (score 4):

We can achieve that by specifying the `migrate` property in the model. Its default value is `alter` which attempt to auto-migrate the schema on every alteration.

```
module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  migrate: 'safe',
  adapter: 'mysql',

  attributes: {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For all models you can change in confing/models.js

```
migrate: 'safe',
```