# Sails.js server won't restart, stalls at 'starting app', due to db collection size

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a sails.js app which has been running for a while but now all of a sudden it crashed due to some random JS error, when trying to restart it simply stays at 'starting app' in the log file.  I don't see anything blocking the binding to the port on the server and I don't see anything else in the logs.  Does anyone know of a way to debug what might be causing the app to not start all of a sudden?  Also this is running on the newest version of node, sails v0.10rc4 and ubuntu 12.04lts

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After some more research this appears to be due to the size of my database.  Whenever I have a collection in mongo over 10,000 records it is basically causing the CPU to stall at 100% as waterline is trying to load the collection into memory.  Anyone know of a way to prevent sails.js from doing this?  I feel that a collection of 10,000 records and a file size of around 30-50mb should be considered tiny for a mongo based app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the sails.js team, it is due to auto migration being set on by default, in production with large datasets you obviously won't want to run this.  Migration can be turned off via the model settings. Info is located at - [Stop the auto migration of the schema in the sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490853/stop-the-auto-migration-of-the-schema-in-the-sailsjs/20516203#20516203)