# Remote SQL Server with sails js

Tags: sql-server, sails.js

I'm trying to use sails js with a SQL Server database, and when try to connect after created a `dbo.AREA` model and controller, sails says:

> error: Hook failed to load: orm (RequestError: There is already an object named 'area' in the database.)
>   error: Error encountered while loading Sails core!
>   error: RequestError: There is already an object named 'area' in the database.

The model code is:

```
module.exports = {
   attributes: {
    CODIGO_CC: 'string',
    CODIGO_AREA: 'string',
    NOMBRE_AREA: 'string',
   }
};
```

and I have another question how can handle the primary keys, because the database doesn't have `id` column.

regards

Comment: Your first question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490853/stop-the-auto-migration-of-the-schema-in-the-sailsjs).

Comment: As for your second question, if you can't find an answer on SO or the [new Sails docs](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Models/Attributes.html), please post it as a separate question so that it can help others!

Comment: Thanks Scott!!migrate: 'safe', was the solution!